# crosstab-query or virtuals to save data using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a json object which i like to save in mongodb,

```
{
    "user": "abc",
    "week": 21,
    "year": 2021
    "data": [
        {
            "date": "01/01/21",
            "present": true
        },
        {
            "date": "02/01/21",
            "present": false
        }
    ]
}
```

this has to be split into 2 tables: timesheet-main and timesheet-data

timesheet-main.model will be like this:

```
{
    "user": "abc",
    "week": 21,
    "year": 2021,
    data: {
        ref: timesheet-data.model
    }
}
```

AND `timesheet-data.model` will be like this:

```
{
    {
        user: userIdFrom-timesheet-main.model,
        timesheet-main-id: timesheet-main-ref-from-above-collection,
        "date": "02/01/21",
        "present": false
    }
}
```

so that when I want week wise user query, i get result like this:

```
{
    "_id": "asf5sf44sdw3sfsf",
    "user": "abc",
    "week": 21,
    "year": 2021
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "Asdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsf",
            "date": "01/01/21",
            "present": true
        },
        {
            "_id": "egdfgfhfghfghfgh"
            "date": "02/01/21",
            "present": false
        }
    ]
}
```

I dont know any good or easy way of doing this, so while saving data in `timesheet-main.model`, after its success, i am calling another insert into `timesheet-data.model`, and saving data in this. But someone suggeted that there can be better way of doing this using Virtuals. I tried but no success.

Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to implement a one-to-many relationship in mongo. You could follow on [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) link.

As for the model:

**timesheet-main.model** [Parent]

```
{
    "data": [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: timesheet-data.model }]
}
```

**timesheet-data.model** [Child]

```
{
    "timesheet-main-id": { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: timesheet-main.model },
}
```

Consider additional fields as per choice. I am only adding fields for a one-to-many relationship.

For adding data -

```
const parent = new TimesheetMain({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    data: []
})
const child  = new TimesheetData()
child.timesheet-main-id = parent._id
child.save(err => HandlerErr)
parent.data.push(child)
parent.save(err=> HandlerErr)
```

Comment: Answer almost OK, but i didn't keep, parent ref in child.