# Is it possible to push a Mongoose obj schema into an array?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've connected my express app to a MongoDB Atlas cluster. This is what I have, and it's currently posting data to it:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const applicantSchema = new Schema(
    {
        _name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        _a1: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        ...etc
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

const Applicant = mongoose.model("Applicant", applicantSchema);

module.exports = Applicant;
```

When the data is logged to the console, I'm seeing:

```
{
  _name: 'fsd',
  _a1: 'x',
  _a2: 'y',
  _a3: 'z'
}
```

**Question:** Is it possible to display the schema's results as an array, like:

```
[{
  _name: 'fsd',
  _a1: 'x',
  _a2: 'y',
  _a3: 'z'
}]
```

Comment: Your question is (at least to me) quite unclear. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: @eol I wanted to know if it's possible to display the results from `applicantSchema` as an array, or if it has to be an object

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. What you are looking for is a one-to-many relationship.
You can use [check mongoose docs here.](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Also, you can find an eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752965/9964717)